# why the size of disk image decreased after mkfs.ext2

Tags: linux, fdisk

first, i create a disk image use `dd`:

```
> dd if=/dev/zero of=disk bs=512 count=2097152
> du -h disk
     1.1G   disk
```

second, `fdisk disk` create a partion:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk disk: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x40c73f2f

Device Boot Start       End  Blocks  Id System
disk1        2048   2097151 1047552  83 Linux
```

blocks column: 1047552, so sectors is : 1024(can fdisk set sector size?).

third, `losetup`:

```
 losetup /dev/loop0 -o 2097152 --sizelimit=1072693248 disk
```

2048*1024 = 2097152  1047552*1024 = 1072693248.

at this time the size of disk is 1G:

```
> du -h disk
  1.1G  disk
```

forth, `mkfs.ext2`:

```
> mkfs.ext2 /dev/loop0
    mke2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
    Discarding device blocks: done                            
    Filesystem label=
    OS type: Linux
    Block size=4096 (log=2)
    Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
    Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
    65408 inodes, 261632 blocks
    13081 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
    First data block=0
    Maximum filesystem blocks=268435456
    8 block groups
    32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
    8176 inodes per group
    Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

    Allocating group tables: done                            
    Writing inode tables: done                            
    Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

and disk image size is decreased:

```
> du -h disk
    19M disk
```

You know filesystem block size is 4096, and have 8 block groups, 32768 blocks per group.

4096 * 8 * 32768 = 1G.

Comment: You get the size of the disk image by doing `ls -l disk` not by any multiplication of sectors and size and then rounding to the nearest 1G (or have a program do that). Please give the exact values of `ls -l disk` after `dd` and after `mkfs.ext2` on the loop device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `discard` option in `mke2fs` is on by default. In newer kernels, doing a `BLKDISCARD` on a loop device causes a hole to be punched on the underlying file, so that that file becomes sparse.

On an ATA drive, the `BLKDISCARD` would translate to a `TRIM`, the idea being that `mke2fs` tells the layer underneath that the data is unallocated so it can do optimisations based on that information (unallocate the space in the file for `loop` devices, recycle flash cells for SSDs...).

If you want to disable that, just do:

```
mkfs.ext2 -E nodiscard /dev/loop0p1
```